# How to access two fields inside a subcollection inside EACH userID document in Firestore Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to access the fields lat: "" and lng: "" that are saved inside a subcollection "userLocations" inside that userID document in the main collection "locations". Here is a screenshot of what it looks like.

As you can see I have a userID that saves lats and lngs.
[image]

[image]

I CAN access all lat, and lng of each document inside userLocation collection but for ONE USER ONLY if and only if I copy and paste that userID.

Here is the code that I used to access only one user's lat and lng:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      try {
        const mainCollectionLocations = collection(db, "locations");
        const userDocRef = doc(
          mainCollectionLocations,
          "LhCNVWJt5bdI0slgBPnbmESrwJh1" //PROBLEM I need to go through all documents available
        );
        const userLocationSubCollection = collection(
          userDocRef,
          "userLocation"
        );

        onSnapshot(userLocationSubCollection, (querySnapshot) => {
          let loc = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            lat: doc.data().lat,
            lng: doc.data().lng,
          }));
          setLocations(loc);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetch();
  }, []);
```

BUT I CANNOT iterate over EACH user getting each user's lat and lng. Here is the current code I'm using in order to try to accomplish this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      try {
        const mainCollectionLocations = collection(db, "locations");
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(mainCollectionLocations);

        let allLocations = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
          console.log("start for loop");
          console.log("doc-ref:", doc.ref);
          const userLocationSubCollection = collection(doc.ref, "userLocation");
          console.log("userLocationSubCollection: ", userLocationSubCollection);
          // const subQuerySnapshot = await getDocs(userLocationSubCollection);

          onSnapshot(userLocationSubCollection, (querySnapshot) => {
            console.log("querySnapShot: ", querySnapshot);

            let loc = querySnapshot.docs.filter((doc) => ({
              lat: doc.data().lat,
              lng: doc.data().lng,
            }));
            console.log("locationsLOc: ", loc);
            allLocations = [...allLocations, ...loc];
            setLocations(allLocations);
          });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetch();
  }, [])
```

PLEASE HELP; I've been stuck for a week already trying to get this data.

Comment: The document IDs that you see in italics do not exist at all in the database.  The reason why you see them in the console is because there are nested subcollections under them.  A query on a collection will not return documents that don't exist even if they have subcollections.  If you want the "missing" documents to show up in a query for all documents in the collection, you should ensure the document exists, even if it doesn't have any fields.